# 'list assignment index out of range' Error How To Fix?

Tags: python, html, pygame

so I made this short script where if I collide with a platform it should delete 1 of my health but I am getting this error

VIdeo OF What I am Trying To Say <-- as you can see if I collide with the my ice tiles it should delete one of my players health --

```
 'list assignment index out of range'
```

```
            for dude in range(len(platforms)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(platforms[dude].rect):
                    del healths[dude]
```

my full code cant fit in so I made it a pastebin
[script](https://pastebin.com/raw/LrSXSadM)

Comment: Are you sure `healths` and `platforms` have the same length?

Comment: It seems like `dude` is likely not within the indexes of either `healths` or `platforms` so I'd recommend adding a print statement to your for loop of both of those things. Additionally, we (SO community) need some more context for this problem to help better (more code).

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 1):

Check if element is present before deleting it.

```
for dude in range(len(platforms)-1,-1,-1):
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(platforms[dude].rect):
        if dude < len(healths): #Check
            del healths[dude]
```

Comment: [gameplay](https://gyazo.com/b72d20dc7aef1a28a564ec8046268104) '    health' object has no attribute 'len'   I dont know why its saying  [what I did](https://gyazo.com/0d4afbe0046aa67900df39ccb1f4512e)  [tile](https://gyazo.com/1caaaef98175efc723cde0e4f15d587f) and my [health class](https://gyazo.com/dccd892cfbb098896b7b1b67365fbf10) I used list to store and add stuff

Comment: It is working now ? 
Also, it's len(healths) and not len(health). In the comment you have mentioned 'health'.

Comment: its working but for some reason it deletes all my health lol is there a way I could move it back when I collide ones? cus like its looking like I am constantly colliding [video](https://gyazo.com/4a85791ce3f3f92362e43321f277abb0)

Comment: It will delete all the health because you are iterating over the complete range of platforms which I guess is equal to 5 or more. Limit it to one or so.

Comment: make the square? for the tile platform smaller? the collision hitbox?

Answer (score 1):

it is not entirely clear why yo are going backwards through the platforms instead of forward through the platforms list based on the code here. Is there more code in that for loop?

Anyway, the range() spec used is going to keep it within the range of the list `platforms`, so that suggests that it is the list `healths` that is going out of range.

Is health actually a list? That is an odd way to manage/keep track of a players health. You usually just do that with a counter. What are `healths`?

Anyway, why would the lists `health` and `platforms` be the same size? That seems the obvious problem. It seems like you are managing health by having a bunch of objects that each represent a unit of health somehow and that to delete a unit of health you delete something of the `healths` list. If that is the idea then to delete an entry from `healths` it should not matter which entry from `healths` you remove. You can just delete the last entry on the list with `healths.pop()` (which removes the last entry and is the most efficient to delete).

```
for dude in range(len(platforms)-1,-1,-1):
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(platforms[dude].rect):
        healths.pop()
```

However this still seems like a very odd way of tracking health. I would suggest that you reexamine this.